# How do I configure a nonexistent database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to configure a nonexistent database for my Rails 3.1 app, using postresql. How do I do this?

Comment: A non-existent database?  Those are... Tricky to configure, because... They don't exist, you see?

Comment: Much like an [invisible bike](http://icanhascheezburger.com/2007/01/25/invisible-bike-2/)

Comment: devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting ... "To debug this locally, configure a nonexistent database in your local config/database.yml and attempt to run rake assets:precompile"

Answer (score 1):

I believe, based on the comments on this question, that what the instruction probably really means, is that you should configure your application to use a particular database, only that database does not actually exist.
 The reason you might do this would be for a particular troubleshooting step. (I lack context to guess why).

A possible method to do this would be to configure your application to a real database, but then change the url or ip address such that the application can't find the database.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have postgresql installed on your system, and your database.yml is properly configured, you should just be able to run `rake db:create` to create the database.  I believe you may also need to install the pg gem.

Comment: The database would then exist, wouldn't it?

Comment: when I first read the question, I took "configure" to mean "create".  After seeing his additional comments, it appears this is not at all what he was looking for...